# footer contant not changing when cache enabled

Tags: footer

magento/app/design/frontend/argento/argento/template/page/html/footer.phtml

This is the file in which i added dynamic content. It works fine when cache is disabled. But when I enabled cache then it does not work. It display the line which display at first refresh.

Any kind of help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

If your your changes are visible when cache is disabled, enable cache and compile.

You can compile in the backend Admin->System->Tools->Compilation

Or via terminal in your project root directory

```
php shell/compiler.php compile
```

Answer (score 0):

In a clean magento install the footer is always static, so the footer being cached is the expected behaviour.

If you have added dynamic content in the footer block you'll need to disable cache for it. You can do that by adding this to your local.xml

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
         <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
         <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```